# Why isn't my javascript function working

Tags: javascript, html

My function is pulling information from an api and then putting it into the table. for some reason this function is not working.

this is my function:

```
function getPayInfo(socCode) {
    var apiurl = "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay?soc=";
    var apicall = apiurl + socCode;
    $.get(apicall, function(data) {
        $("#Pay tbody").html("");
        $.each(data.years, function(i, e) {
            var tablerow = $("<tr></tr>");
            tablerow.append("<td>" + e.year + "</td>");
            tablerow.append("<td>" + e.estpay + "</td>");
            $("#Pay tbody").append(tablerow);
        });
    }); 
}
```

and this is the table i am putting it into:

```
<div class="well table table-stripped">
    <h4>Pay Information</h4>
    <h5>Pounds per Week</h5>
    <table id="Pay">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Estimate Pay</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

i expected it to return a year and data value into the table. if you take the url in the function and add a certain 4 fuigure value(the socCode) to the end it will give the data online this should then be returned to the table body

Comment: Try to explain what `exactly not working`, people with telepathy are having rest.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What part of it is not working. Also you need to have a more specific title then this.

Comment: i expected it to return a year and data value into the table. if you take the url in the function and add a certain 4 fuigure value(the socCode) to the end it will give the data online this should then be returned to the table body

Comment: @Samy447, one of the first things that I would check is whether the result of your get call is actually executing.  For example, you could put an alert in the body of your anonymous function.  The function might not be executing, for instance, if your actual http request is malformed or incorrectly processed on the server.  If the function *does* execute, then the problem is likely with how you append values to your table.  If it does not, then you might want to use jquery's .ajax call instead with an error function so that you can at least see why it fails.  Either way, post back the results.

Comment: @BehramMistree, all it says when i run the function is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". so it is executing just not returning any results. also where should i put an alert and what should i put.

Comment: I would comment out the body of the function that you pass to $.get and put the alert there.  Eg., alert('got here!');  Even better, maybe you could print the contents of the data object you get back.  Eg., alert(data);.  The error that your describing might arise from assuming that data has a particular form that it does not.  As a side note, all the previous commenters that asked about what wasn't working would have loved to know about that error message.  It's a great example of something that should have been in your original post.  You live, you learn.

Answer (score -1):

You are not executing the function `getPayInfo`. So maybe that is why the code is not giving you any output.

You can try to get the errors from the Inspector of your browser in the Networks tab.

If the event is trigerring, and the request is being sent, it will be logged there and there you can see the HTTP message of the page, whether it is a 404 or the 500 which is causing this error.

Otherwise, I think that the element selectors aren't properly selected.